# Mock SOAP service works in SoapUI but not with Spring Integration

Tags: spring, soap, spring-integration, soapui

I set up a mock SOAP service in SoapUI following the guide [here](https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/getting-started.html). When executing the CurrencyConvertorSoap12 Request 1 within SoapUI, I get the appropriate response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:web="http://www.webserviceX.NET/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <web:ConversionRateResponse>
         <web:ConversionRateResult>2.34</web:ConversionRateResult>
      </web:ConversionRateResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I want to test it using the Spring Integration web service outbound gateway.

I set up a web service test (the String `requestXML` below is the same XML request in SoapUI):

```
@Test
public void webServiceTest() {

    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Context.xml");

    DestinationResolver<MessageChannel> channelResolver = new BeanFactoryChannelResolver(context);

    String requestXml = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">"
                        + "<soap:Header/>"
                        + "<soap:Body>"
                        + "<web:ConversionRate>"
                        + "<web:FromCurrency>?</web:FromCurrency>"
                        + "<web:ToCurrency>?</web:ToCurrency>"
                        + "</web:ConversionRate>"
                        + "</soap:Body>"
                        + "</soap:Envelope>";

    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestXml).build();
    MessageChannel channel = channelResolver.resolveDestination("wsInChannel");

    channel.send(message);
}
```

`Context.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-stream="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream"
    xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
    xmlns:int-ftp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ftp"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws.xsd">

    <int:channel id="wsInChannel"/>

    <int:chain input-channel="wsInChannel" output-channel="stdoutChannel">
        <int-ws:header-enricher>
            <int-ws:soap-action value="http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate"/>
        </int-ws:header-enricher>
        <int-ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://localhost:8088/mockCurrencyConvertorSoap12"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:channel id="stdoutChannel"/>
    <int-stream:stdout-channel-adapter
        id="consumer" channel="stdoutChannel" append-newline="true" />

</beans>
```

When I run the test, I get this error in SoapUI:

```
Thu Jun 09 11:50:21 EDT 2016:ERROR:An error occurred [Missing operation for soapAction [http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate] and body element [{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]], see error log for details
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IMHO not reading XML from files is one wrong thing you're doing

Comment: @ThomasRS This was only a proof of concept. This isn't normally how I would read in the XML.

Comment: Then show us your JAXB utility ;-) I suggest you also evaluate using CXF and generate a webservice client; you'll get the server endpoint mock too. I've put up an example [here](https://github.com/skjolber/mockito-soap-cxf) which will let you discard SoapUI, at least for unit testing.

Comment: @ThomasRS The question was about how to properly send a SOAP request using Spring Integration, not the tools used to read in XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and body element [{http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope}Envelope]

But you send the whole SOAP `Envelope`, not just `Body` as it requests.

So, your `requestXml` must be like:

```
"<web:ConversionRate xmlns:web=\"http://www.webserviceX.NET/\">"
+ "<web:FromCurrency>?</web:FromCurrency>"
+ "<web:ToCurrency>?</web:ToCurrency>"
+ "</web:ConversionRate>"
```

And don't forget to replace `?` with an appropriate currencies :-)

Comment: When I made that change I get this error: `[Fatal Error] :1:21: The prefix "web" for element "web:ConversionRate" is not bound.
ERROR:  'The prefix "web" for element "web:ConversionRate" is not bound.'`

Comment: I've just added `xmlns:web` to my answer. See updated XML.

Comment: Now getting this error: `Cannot create message: incorrect content-type for SOAP version. Got application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8, but expected text/xml`

Comment: That is what Spring WS produces as a `content-type` header. Just change your SOAP-UI to accept that header instead of simple `text/xml`

Comment: I'm not seeing an option to change it from SoapUI. Is there a way to set the Spring WS header?

Comment: You have to configure `SaajSoapMessageFactory` with `SoapVersion.SOAP_11` and inject it into `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`

Comment: I did this, and it actually worked when I used `SoapVersion.SOAP_12`.